# How to handle questions with wrong or opinion based answers accepted?

Tags: support, answers

I found some of the questions with answers which are inauthentic but accepted by the OP.

People who are beginners to the site may take it in another way.

How to handle the scenario?  Can I mark the answer for deletion?

Comment: Inauthentic answers means which do not have any sources?

Comment: @Rickross Yeah, which does not quote from scriptures.

Comment: You can flag such answers for Mod's intervention .. Btw do u hv any examples?

Comment: Yeah @Rickross I need to see once again.

Comment: @hanugm See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1477) answer. Closely related.