# Is there a procedure to challenge alleged cited material?

Tags: support, answers, sources-and-citations

Reasons could be

(0) No citation

(1) non-existent in the source which the citer cites

(2) Questionable/wrong translation

I am refraining from "interpolation" as a reason since it is very hard to prove

So is there a procedure to challenge such alleged cited material?

Comment: Point0 - You can flag for mod's intervention in this case .. mod's will add a notice/banner to the answer point1 also the same .. flag ... for point2 not sure probably you can comment (under answer) and highlight the issue

Comment: Yes @rickross - something that looks like a system-generated message appears for reason 0 - and is enforced selectively by the powers that be.  It would be good to have uniform policies for validating citations.

Comment: If u see an answer which does not cite anything then u shd obviously flag it for moderator's intervention and a banner will be added to the answer for sure .. so I don't think there is any issue with 0 but whn there is wrong translation and the like then all the debates start..

Comment: Related https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-to-handle-translation-issues-in-answer-or-some-part-of-answer-is-wrong-or-an

Comment: Also, if translation/ source accuracy is of concern, if could include information that is an alternative and precisely cited, could be helpful. Thank you  :)

Answer (score -2):

I would like a status called "no source" or "source challenged" for answers with questionable sources.   Something like this already exists partially for no source and unacceptable source, but a direct challenge of alleged scripture doesn't exist.  And this feature seems to be system/mod generated and is selectively implemented by the mods.  This right should be given to all and implemented transparently.

posters should be given a fixed period of time to answer factual challenges, and if they don't respond their answers should be deleted.

For sources allegedly taken from the internet - A CLICKABLE LINK SHOULD BE MANDATORY.

Comment: That would simply start a firefight between the already entrenched factions here on HSE. I am sure some would be happy to have it, but it is a double edged sword and pretty sure not many would actually like how it works in the end. Sometimes I have to wonder if this site is actually helping anyone.