# Moderation on Hi SE of inappropriate posts

Tags: discussion

I'd like someone to explain something. Recently I flagged a post, an answer [How do Dvaitins and Vishistadvaitins interpret this passage of Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12137/how-do-dvaitins-and-vishistadvaitins-interpret-this-passage-of-mahabharata/26215#26215)

answered Mar 26 at 11:39 by Pradip Gangopadhyay

> This answer is written according to Advaita Vedanta system, but that is not what the question asks! This answer should be removed. – brahma jijnasa 2 days ago

and I got a notification:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

On what grounds it's declined?

Comment: Not the one who handled it, but looks like answer says  passage doesn't support Advaita  and  it needs an assumption that there is no ego to make it compatible with Advaita. So, in this sense answer refutes "opinion" of OP that passage supports Advaita.

Comment: @TheD Thanks for your response. But even if the poster P.Gangopadhyay is right about what he is posting, his answer is not an answer to the Q because Q asks what Vaishnava traditions think about that Mbh passage, please read the Q. And the answer also says this: "So the passage is consistent with Advaita Vedanta ...". So it's clear, as far as I can see, that the post doesn't answer the Q. I've seen there are many answers on Hi SE which actually do not answer the Q which is asked. This is just one example of it. I think our moderators should take care about it.

Comment: Actually he says "So the passage is consistent with Advaita Vedanta *if we accept that Suka was not at that time in the highest stage*" This is against what OP says where he assumes or of opinion that passage supports Advaita.  If a question has some assumption or if a user feels question has some assumption, refuting  that assumption can also be considered as answer. But here answer *also* says what needs to done to make it compatible with Advaita.  Anyways, i will comment under the answer so that we can be sure what Pradip wanted to convey.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is a "wrong answer"? What is the official policy on handling wrong answers?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/what-exactly-is-a-wrong-answer-what-is-the-official-policy-on-handling-wrong)

Comment: @TheD *If a question has some assumption or if a user feels question has some assumption, refuting that assumption can also be considered as answer.* -- I thought we're supposed to answer only what has been asked and not assumptions. If Q wanted to ask also what's Advaitins opinion he would have asked "What Advaitins and Vaishnavas think about that Mbh ...", but he didn't ask for Advaitin's explanation, he asked only for Vaishnava explanation.