# About marking a question Duplicate after four days of posting it

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates, declined-flags

I am here discussing about the question : [Which of the six Darshanas are atheistic?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34664/5212)

**It was marked as duplicate after four days of the original question being posted, by one Moderator who answered the original question!**. In the mean time, the question got attention of many and several upvotes and downvotes also.

When I flagged the [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34696/5212) by OP, it was declined with following reason:

> 'This denigrates many sects'. – commonman Apr 27 at 18:05   **declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it**

When I again  pointed to the moderators that one answer is denigrating different sects, I was informed by one moderator in chat.

> I think it would be the case of wrong answer and wrong interpretation. This isn't seem denigrating a sect but rather seems **spoiling the philosophies**

My question is: how can it take this much time to mark a question duplicate by someone whose answer to the original question was accepted? Also, can the 'spoiling of the Philosophies' be silently observed by the moderators? Is 'Spoiling' not 'denigrating'?

Comment: Moderators are not always free to check each and every question. I guess they were busy.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I have not posted it to kniw what you guess!

Comment: My point is you cannot expect swift action from moderators always. They can always be busy.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury All were busy together on this sensitive question and answer and some were busy as usual to appreciate and defend the answer by the OP. That sounds really fine:-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm one of them who's appreciating and defending the answer :P

Comment: @commonman I have been following this page. It's very disheartening to find that a healthy on-going debate has been censured like this.

Comment: although i have voted to reopen the question, I'd like to know what exactly is the difference between the 2 questions ?

Comment: The [linked question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34664) is not a duplicate of the [other question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21226) and should be re-opened. The question is specifically asking which sects are atheistic while the other question is a very generic one. The answers could be common/duplicate but the question themselves are different.

Comment: @sv. Yes it IS duplicate with a far better answer.

Answer (score 4):

We do not need moderators to close or reopen questions. We should not wait for moderators to do such things. So, late closure in general shows the users are not active in moderation.

Five users with a reputation of 500 are enough. If there is a reopen vote, then the question will be pushed into the review queue. Other users shall review the post.

Also, any question can be closed or reopened any time. There is no time limit that a question should be closed after/before a specific period of time. There are instances a question was closed within a 10 minutes of time. At the same time, it was also closed after months too. We need not to depend on moderators to close. We are given privileges. So, we should use them wisely. **Only thing we have to keep in mind is whether the justification of closure**. We should check the selected closure reason is correct. Even if it's a moderator who did wrong closure, the decision can be reversed.

About answers received, it is on the users' part to wait to know if the question is duplicate or closeable. Users should check whether the new question asked is okay in its current form i.e., if it is

1. a duplicate
2. an opinion based or controversial question
3. too broad
4. Off-topic

After the question is fit, we can write answers. Writing answers to every question without checking the question is not good for the site. It only helps the OP. But our goal is to help many along with OP.

The specific answer by OP mentions it is written according to Tatva Viveka, a text by Bhaktivinoda Thakur. Most of the arguments are from that text. In the ancient times, many philosophers wrote many works refuting other schools of philosophy. I have to agree with the moderators that it can be considered as wrong interpretation and difference in opinion between sects and philosophies. They can't be deleted unless they are exceptional cases where the users themseves adds their own personal views and other. See [What exactly is a "wrong answer"? What is the official policy on handling wrong answers?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/5212)

Comment: @commonman If you want only from moderators, do not post it on meta. On meta, anyone can answer as it is posted for discussion. Contact them on Moderation room. This question is not a flag decline or something only moderators can answer.

Comment: One should take time to read the question minutely and be sensible enough to answer it  properly.

Comment: "One shouldvtake time to read the question minutely and be sensible enough to answer it properly" Yes, more or less that is what I said in the answer. The users should check for duplicates and then answer without writing answer to every question and then post rant later. A question can be closed any time. That is the point you did not know. The question should be whether if it is correct closure or not.

Comment: Your title is mainly focusing on the time period it is posted. It doesn't matter if it is four days or a week. The action should be swift, I agree. You should make it clear in the title on the body what is your question exactly. I understood your question completely. You ask how can the closure be four days late, also how can close the question and about allowing the answer which you linked. There are users who do not know the policies completely and can't be clear which answer they are talking about. That advice is for them.

Comment: 'You need not to flag your answer for moderator's attention for deleting.' -what does this part of your answer mean? Where in the question I have mentioned about flagging my answer? Please read the question carefully and please do not provide such meaningless answer.

Comment: @commonman Can you please check where does the answer link in the meta question take? You said question and then link to your own answer and you say you have flagged the answer. What was happening? Post your question clearly and then you can say to others. Use proper language and don't use words like meaningless or similar.

Comment: I linked the question.This is a problem most likely of the android software.But it is common sense that one would nof flag own answer!

Comment: There are people who can't link properly. How can I expect it that they won't flag their own answer? You linked to your own answer. Use mobile web or select share option under question or answer and paste the link. Giving wrong links is totally misleading.

Comment: There are people who do not read tye question minutely inspite of repeated request! It is obvious that the question was marked duplicate and I linked the question.It is also obvious that I would not flag my answer.

Comment: seems like you read question toooooo minutely...