# The Bias of the Moderators of this Site?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

I write here to complain about the bias of the moderators of this site. My strong complaint is against Vedantic moderators like Pandya and a few others like him, who cannot moderate in a dispassionate manner.

Through this post, I am ready for discussion.

A few days ago, Pandya was involved in moderating my post, wherein he was silent to the abusive language used against Dayananda. Even he went one step ahead and posed himself the question as to who accorded the title of Maharishi to  Dayananda.

The question itself is a valid question, I have no objections to the question per se. But the timing of the question and the fact that during his moderation he was not at all sensitive when the other users were using words like bogus, neo-Vedantic, lack of Sanskrit knowledge against Dayananda.

I am new to this site, hence I was not aware of the flagging the post concept! But still, that does not mean the moderator was not aware of such words being an abuse.

I am not a follower of Dayananda or member of Arya Samaj. I am writing this post to highlight the unfair moderation practices!

Comment: Which post? Could you share the the link?

Comment: -1, blank rant with no backing for the said accusations.

Answer (score 2):

> I am new to this site, hence I was not aware of the flagging the post concept!

Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Go through [help](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help) to know how Stack Exchange works. Read [FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/277) to learn more about this community.

> A few days ago, Pandya was involved in moderating my post, wherein he was silent to the abusive language used against Dayananda.

I think you are talking about [your deleted answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37136/277). Neither question nor any answer to that question mentioned about Swami Dayananda Saraswati. I see it is [your comment only](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/were-women-cursed-with-menstruation/37136#comment119062_37136) which says " A few days ago someone was saying Dayananda is neo-Vedantic, bogus etc. etc." but no link is provided to trace what your are referring to. By the way, reason for deletion of your answer in explained in last two comments, check them if your concern is to know why your answer is deleted.

> Even he went one step ahead and posed himself the question as to who accorded the title of Maharishi to Dayananda.

The only post I did discuss about "Swami Dayananda Saraswati and Vedanta" is [this answer post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36861/277) which seems fine, nothing rude or against him. [The question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35080/277) you're mentioning is not posted by me. That post seems fine too.

> My strong complaint is against Vedantic moderators like Pandya and a few others like him, who cannot moderate in a dispassionate manner.

Regardless of which philosophy one personally believes in, All of the 6 Asktia schools of philosophies are accepted here and all sects are respected here.

Comment: "The question you're mentioning is not posted by me." Even if you have posted, it wouldn't make any difference. It's just a question asking how Dayananda Saraswati got the title. I think it's worth mentioning that not only all the sects, all religions are respected here. The deleted answer would even fit deletion using red flag. It was rude.

Comment: @Pandya .. No, it was to another question. Anyhow, I will move ahead for now and closely observe and document my perceptions of biased moderations in future so that record is available!

Comment: @user965167 which bias? Can your provide link?

Answer (score 1):

I agree to this issue.

I have been observing the biased attitude of this particular and only active moderator.

I am quoting 2 incidents, in which this particular moderator is involved.

---

1. When the moderator himself posts a wrong answer.

This moderator posted an [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37004/3869), which is wrong, to a question [Is there any sukta in Rigveda containing 16 richas and starting with the word“Indra”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36989/3869)

I had pointed out that issue, On November 11, 2019, which is as follows:

> OP had mentioned that (1) there should be 16 Rochas and (2) if the
>   aforementioned 16 Richas are chanted daily then one is blessed with
>   intelligence, friends and fulfillment of desires. RV 1.32 contains 15
>   only. Please check

However, neither the answer was modified nor was not deleted, as it is a wrong answer.  As usual, his group of friends in this site, remained silent.

2. I had posted an [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/39841/3869) to the question [How is Bramhana part of Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/38826/3869), duly quoting the [source of the answer](https://qr.ae/pNvgbH).

As I did not want to meddle with the original answer posted in Quora, keeping in view of the original author's knowledge, I just copied the answer and pasted.  This is not the first time that I did so.

Still, this moderator posted the following comment.

> Read copy-paste issue. We are not here to reproduce the same text from
>   one QA site to another. You should write in your own words, citing
>   authentic sources. (Although you may mention the credit to quora but
>   it doesn't mean we should just copy-paste from Quora)

---

3. In one of the comments, ***which was deleted by moderator,*** I had stated as follows:

> When you want to say **get out from this site**, but **cannot say** due to
>   rules of the site, you can make the life miserable to that particular
>   member, so that he will take exit by himself.  In our Telugu, there is
>   a saying పొమ్మనలేక పొగ పెట్టడం.

***Perhaps, some members belonging to one sect, is implementing this method here***

Comment: Let me reply your 3 points: 1. Moderators are also human. So, it is possible that answer posted may not be 100% correct. Wrong answer should be downvoted, not deleted, visit [this QA](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/678/277). 2. Copy pasting from Quora and Wikipedia should not be encouraged. 3. I don't understand Telugu saying but I don't belong to any sect.

Comment: You are twisting the rules according to your whims and fancies.  If copy and paste is not encouraged,  then why was Notice is provided under each question **Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook.**.  What difference does it make if someone from outside sends an answer through a link or a member copying another answer and pasting it here, duly giving credit to the original author.  @Pandya

Comment: Let's continue discussion in [chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism)

Answer (score -1):

Certainly, the majority of users and many moderators of this website are biased.

There is recorded proof of this bias on this website. There is a coterie that has a certain way to look to the "correctness" of an answer.

The coterie is exposed in the "[Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)" See point 5. where the coterie has as the yardstick of "Prasthana" to measure the "correctness" of the answer.

Why should all the user be measured on the yardstick of Prasthana? This is a million-dollar question!

This is recorded evidence of the way the coterie groups together to judge an answer, downvote it, close the question and many other acts that point to the rigged practices on this website.

So now we have an excess of users who believe in Prasthana and anything that does not fit their yardstick is "incorrect". Then these users group to downvote the answers, close the question by casting their votes and so on. They upvote their own Prasthan based answers. This, in turn, provides them privileges, which are subsequently abused.

Such practices will amount to infringement of Anti-trust laws, principles of natural justice.